# SQL Server Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows (chars) or when the subquery is used as an expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to update some fields based on their occurence. If they only occur one time, I am updating some status field.

My current code is as follows:

```
UPDATE table1
SET statusField = 1
WHERE someID = (
               SELECT someID
               FROM table1
               GROUP BY someID HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
               )
```

This returns an error like the one in the title: `Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.`

Is there any other, as easily readable/simple, solution to this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use `IN` keyword instead of equals operator like so:

```
UPDATE table1
SET statusField = 1
WHERE someID IN (
           SELECT someID
           FROM table1
           GROUP BY someID HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
           )
```

Using `=` requires that exactly 1 result is returned by the subquery. `IN` keyword works on a list.

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing that out! Ran perfectly this time.

Comment: `GROUP BY someID HAVING COUNT(*) = 1` is not required here.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You should join your tables in the subselect. It is possible to use 'in', but in your case I would use exists:

```
UPDATE table1 x
SET statusField = 1
WHERE exists (
               SELECT null
               FROM table1
               WHERE x.someID = someID
               GROUP BY someID 
               HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
               )
```

For better performance I would use this script instead (sqlserver-2008+):

```
;WITH x as
(
SELECT rc = count() over (partition by someID), statusField
FROM table1
)
UPDATE x
SET statusField = 1
WHERE rc = 1
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up with using the IN operator as the query only had to run through just under 50 rows, so not too large of a query.

However, I will add this to my reportoire! Thank you, again! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Use **Top**

```
UPDATE table1
SET statusField = 1
WHERE someID = (
               SELECT TOP 1 someID
               FROM table1
               GROUP BY someID HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
               )
```

Or you can use **IN** clause

```
UPDATE table1
SET statusField = 1
WHERE someID IN (
               SELECT someID
               FROM table1
               GROUP BY someID HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
               )
```

Comment: your first suggestion will not return a useful answer