# c# I want update sql different Value but Error Help me

Tags: c#, sql-server

StockCalulate Aleart

**Picture 1:**

[image]

**Picture 2:**

[image]

**CODE:**

```
try {

 con = new SqlConnection(cs.DBConn);
 con.Open();
 string cb = "Update OrderDetailNum set ImportPrice = (@d1 /100) * (select StockCalulate=((StockCalulate/Sum(StockCalulate))*100) from OrderDetailNum  Where StockID='" + lblStockID.Text + "' AND Orderid='" + comboOrder.Text + "' group by StockCalulate) Where StockID='" + lblStockID.Text + "' AND Orderid='" + comboOrder.Text + "'";
 cmd = new SqlCommand(cb);
 cmd.Connection = con;
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d1", Convert.ToDecimal(lblPr.Text.ToString()));
 cmd.ExecuteReader();
 con.Close();
 MessageBox.Show("Successfully updated", "Record", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
 dataGridView1.DataSource = GetData();
 ClearAllText(this);
} catch (Exception ex) {
 MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

Comment: Your seems more a SQL problem, I would edit the question and put focus only on the query.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows (chars) or when the subquery is used as an expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22909737/sql-server-subquery-returned-more-than-1-value-this-is-not-permitted-when-the-s)

Comment: [***SQL Injection alert***](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score -1):

Try following

```
            string cb = string.Format("Update OrderDetailNum set ImportPrice = (@d1 /100) * (select StockCalulate=((StockCalulate/Sum(StockCalulate))*100))" +
                " from OrderDetailNum" +
                " Where StockID='{0}' AND Orderid='{1}'",
                lblStockID.Text, comboOrder.Text);
```

Comment: EROR index zero based must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list

Comment: I removed the last plus sign.